# HTML Tag injection in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, security

My security team reported one html tag injection security issue for the below code

```
 function ClosePopUp(objBhID) {
        var pageName = window.location.pathname;
        var modalPopupBehavior = $find(objBhID);
        if (modalPopupBehavior != null && modalPopupBehavior != 'undefined') {
            modalPopupBehavior.hide();
        }
        if (objBhID == 'bhThankMsg' && pageName == '/Projects/Comm.aspx') {
            var objPartnerID = '<%=Request.QueryString["partnerid"]%>';
            if (objPartnerID != 'undefined' && objPartnerID != null && objPartnerID != '') {
                window.location = '/Projects/Comm.aspx?Id=<%=Request.QueryString["ID"]%>&partnerid=<%=Request.QueryString["partnerid"]%>';                
            }
            else {
                window.location = '/Projects/Comm.aspx?Id=<%=Request.QueryString["ID"]%>';
            }
        }
    }
```

My security team reported the below issue[image]

HTML tag injection vulnerabilities were identified on this web application. HTML tag injections are used to aid in Cross-Site Request Forgeries and phishing attacks against third-party web sites, and can often double as Cross-Site Scripting vulnerabilities. Recommendations include implementing secure programming techniques that ensure proper filtration of user-supplied data, and encoding all user supplied data to prevent inserted scripts being sent to end users in a format that can be executed.

My requirement is i don't want to allow any user or hacker to inject unnecessary data, how to achieve this ?

Comment: ...and what is the actual question?!?

Comment: You need to specify what your problem is. Are you asking how to securely filter user input data or what? I don't see a question mark anywhere in your "question"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the other answer will work in this case for URLs, because the built in URL encoding happens to encode html and Javascript escape characters, this is not a complete solution for using dynamic server-side values within Javascript. Therefore I post my answer here so hopefully no one falls into the trap of using the wrong encoding and produces something insecure.

The [OWASP rule is](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values):

> Except for alphanumeric characters, escape all characters less than
>   256 with the \xHH format to prevent switching out of the data value
>   into the script context or into another attribute. DO NOT use any
>   escaping shortcuts like \" because the quote character may be matched
>   by the HTML attribute parser which runs first. These escaping
>   shortcuts are also susceptible to "escape-the-escape" attacks where
>   the attacker sends \" and the vulnerable code turns that into \"
>   which enables the quote.

However, an easier, and imo simpler solution is to never put server-side data within any script tag or script enabled attribute at all. Use HTML5 data attributes, then you can insert your data HTML encoded into a safer HTML context.

I see you appear to be using JQuery. Why not do the following, then you can use the built-in ASP.NET encoding functions?

```
<div id="myDynamicData" data-partnerId="<%=Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString["partnerid"])%>" data-id="<%=Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString["id"]%>)" />
```

Or simply

```
<div id="myDynamicData" data-partnerId="<%:Request.QueryString["partnerid"]%>" data-id="<%:Request.QueryString["id"]%>" />
```

on newer versions of .NET.

Your code then becomes:

```
function ClosePopUp(objBhID) {
        var pageName = window.location.pathname;
        var modalPopupBehavior = $find(objBhID);
        if (modalPopupBehavior != null && modalPopupBehavior != 'undefined') {
            modalPopupBehavior.hide();
        }
        if (objBhID == 'bhThankMsg' && pageName == '/Projects/Comm.aspx') {
            var objPartnerID = $('#myDynamicData').data('partnerId');
            var id = $('#myDynamicData').data('id');
            if (objPartnerID) {
                window.location = '/Projects/Comm.aspx?Id=' + encodeURIComponent(id) + '&partnerid=' + encodeURIComponent(objPartnerID);                
            }
            else {
                window.location = '/Projects/Comm.aspx?Id=' + encodeURIComponent(id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= HttpUtility.UrlEncode( Request.QueryString["ID"] ) %>
```