# Saving Html from Webpage and Prevent XSS

Tags: jquery, html, xss

I am reading Html from webpage inside div content using jquery

**HTML Code**

```html
<div id="content">
Html Code
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
 var htmlContent = $("#content").html();
```

and saving it directly into database using Ajax Request. But if somebody inject the Html or Javascript code into the Html Content of the page, that is also getting saved into database.

When next time html is loaded on page it is infected with XSS attack. Is there any way I can prevent XSS attack..

Comment: Why are you doing this? I thought it was bad enough to store hard coded HTML on database. The best and most secure way is to not do it. If you post what your trying to achieve maybe a better approach can be given.

Comment: @ste2425 I am creating template for mail dynamically using drag and drop approach. So I am dropping the Html into the div and then user can add his text into that html or can add Image and then on final Save I am saving it into database.

Comment: This could also be a good question to move to security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

ideally,  you will have a datamodel of the html that is being stored, and you will store that model in a format such as json. that json can be used to re-construct the html.

In that json model, you will only include content that is considered safe.

Now, if you still need to store html code in the database and inject it back into a page later, then the only safe option you have is to scour that html on the server, compare its contents with a whitelist of allowed content, and delete whatever is not in your whitelist.

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475784/why-use-a-whitelist-for-html-sanitizing)

Answer (score 0):

The OWASP has a page dedicated to XSS prevention:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

some measures include

- entity encoding
- html validation
- url encoding
- sanitization (whitelist based)
- ...

There is also this point mentioned in the question:

> [...] and saving it directly into database using Ajax Request.

No matter what you do client-side, an attacker can send traffic directly to the endpoint; so don't forget server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

- Use **proper encoding**, make sure no SQL injection can take place
- Provide client-and server side **validation**
- **Sanitize the html** before pushing it into the database stripping off all scripts (see [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization))
- Use **CSP Headers** to avoid inline script execution when displaying the html (see [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP))

With these measures you'll be a lot more secure against possible xss attacks.

Answer (score 0):

HTML in the database should not be a problem - the database server will not execute script stored within data tables.

The problem, as you state, if this is output in raw form to an HTML page.

You should HTML encode in order to prevent XSS - do this on output.

To make this simple use the [OWASP XSS Experimental Minimal Encoding Rules](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Experimental_Minimal_Encoding_Rules).

> - HTML Entity encode < &
> - specify charset in metatag to avoid UTF7 XSS
> - limit input to charset
>     http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets

Many languages already provide HTML encoding functions to do the above - remember, apply these on output and only within an HTML context (i.e. not script, CSS or comments).

If you need to use dynamic values in script, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37878123/413180).

Comment: but what if the requirement is to render the stored html in the browser. Encoding at the point of output will not render html, but will simply display the html as it is. I have the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75689273/how-to-safely-store-html-and-js-in-the-database

Comment: I would recommend a strict [content security policy](https://web.dev/csp/) for pages that output the user-set HTML. I would also employ an industry established HTML sanitiser as a defence-in-depth approach. This can also help protect against any [UI redress attacks](https://www.bugcrowd.com/glossary/ui-redress-attack/).