# Is there any Javascript library that can validate html?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

What I am trying to get is very simple: I have a textbox in my website where i can use html and when i press the "Send" button, the value in that textbox is send to the website. But sometimes a user comes to the site, writes html and forgets to close the tag for example, messing up completly my site.
In order to solve this problem, all i want is a validator that when the button is clicked, it checks whatever was written and inspects if something is incorrect and presents a solution to correct the html problem.
I've seen plataforms like https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html that do exactly what i want but can i use it in my own site?

I tried to do something in my own with Javascript but it's very complex and has a lot of issues.

Can please someone help me?

Comment: Use an IDE to have auto-completion and validation of your WebSite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. I would be severely re-miss if I failed to point out that accepting raw HTML from your users is, generally-speaking, **not a good idea™**.

Doing this incorrectly (and it is an **extremely difficult task to do correctly**) leaves your site, and your users, open to many vulnerabilities.  You can view a partial list of them at https://html5sec.org/ (I say partial because they're only listing the "known" attack vectors).  There are a lot of good answers to [a seemingly-unrelated, but definitely semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959228/saving-html-from-webpage-and-prevent-xss) and I strongly recommend that you read them all.

> "But @Pete!", I hear you cry, "My users are trustworthy. They won't try to click-jack my other users, or do anything else malicious or untowards!"

You may be suffering under the delusion that everyone who uses your site will not be malicious, or [will even be using a browser to submit HTML to your site](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+curl+to+post) (so don't forget server-side validation and sanitization).

Then again, you may not be deluded and your userbase has a vested interest in only submitting safe HTML for your site. Maybe you've already considered, and implemented, bullet-proof client-side and server-side validation and sanitization routines. I don't know your exact circumstances and I won't pretend to (although I do know the probabilities involved here are **not** in your favor).

With all of the above in mind, if you still insist on allowing a user to write and submit raw HTML to your site, consider:

- using the documentation found at  https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html to fire off an [AJAX request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and validate the HTML being submitted;
- using a plugin/library for a [Rich Text Editor](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+rich+text+editor) that lets the user enter in formatted text like they would in a word processor and gives you a resulting HTML string to send to your server.
- using a plugin/library for a [Markdown parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+markdown+parser) (like the one you use here at SO).

You could also just convert the user's HTML to a DOM element (allowing the browser to parse the HTML into an actual DOM element) and then grab the [parsed] HTML string back:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('unsafe-html');
    var button = document.getElementById('get-unsafe-html');
    var getUnsafeHtml = function getUnsafeHtml() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = textarea.value; // parses HTML to DOM elements
        return div.innerHTML; // gets it back in a string form.
    }
    
    
    button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var unsafeHtml = getUnsafeHtml();
        console.log(unsafeHtml);
        
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }, false);
}, false);
```

```html
<textarea id="unsafe-html" rows="5">
    <p>If you <strong>insist</strong>, <i>then</i> this technique can be used as well.</p>
</textarea>
<button id="get-unsafe-html">Get the HTML</button>
```

This will **not** ensure that the markup is the way the user intended it to be, but it will ensure you don't have unmatched tags (as they will be either auto-closed, or removed, depending on the browser).